# How could successfully fostering a working relationship with the U.S. government have helped protect the mafia from prosecution?

Tags: government, criminal-underworld

The Racketeering laws basically killed the mob and prevented any chance of them returning to the glory days. For decades, the mafia godfathers were able to insulate themselves from prosecution, letting their underlings take the fall and protecting the organization.

[RICO](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Racketeer_Influenced_and_Corrupt_Organizations_Act) (The Racketeer Influenced and Corrupt Organizations Act) changed this by allowing them to be charged with running an illegal enterprise, regardless of whether they committed the crimes or not. With the commision trial in the 1990s, followed by the disastrous reign of [the Teflon Don](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/John_Gotti), the government was able to expose the mob and bring them out into the light.

But what if the mob saw this coming years ago and wanted to take steps to prevent it? There have been times throughout the nation's history in which the mob and the government have assisted each other, directly and indirectly.  could the mafia have successfully nurtured these relationships in order to protect themselves from prosecution?

Comment: I added links for those of us who are not very interested/versed in the US criminal history and legislation.

Comment: This seems pretty broad. There are so many different ways that the mob could have attempted to protect themselves from RICO laws. Any one explanation sounds like something you could write a book about.

Comment: RICO was *specifically designed* to target the mob organization and activities. The real only escape is to change the organization radically, change the activities radically, and essentially to give up crime as a business model. Anything short of that is temporary camouflage.